# Rspec missing template error - html+phone.slim (variants) - how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I have a view with the following format:

```
show_map.html+phone.slim
```

I am testing my controller, expecting my test to render that template , does anyone know the proper syntax for rendering a view with variant ?

This is what I am trying:

```
describe "show_map action" do 
  it "renders show map view" do 
  get :show_map, {:id=>@job.id,:format=>:html,:variants=>:phone}
  expect(response).to render_template('show_map')
end
```

also tried

```
  get :show_map, {:id=>@job.id,:format=>'html.phone'}
```

Either way, I get a missing template error:

```
 JobsController show_map action renders show map view
     Failure/Error: get :show_map, {:id=>@job.id,:format=>:html,:variants=>:phone}
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template jobs/show_map, application/show_map with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :slim]}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `:html.phone` well this alone won't work... you're trying to call the `.phone` method on the `:html` symbol??? maybe you meant to try `:format=>"html.phone"` instead? (Note: that said, i don't know enough about variants to give you the right answer..)

Comment: yup thats what i meant! i changed it accordingly:)

Comment: no :( will post here if i get it to work

Comment: darn :( That would have been a nice, easy fix if it had worked...

Comment: when "variants" gets passed through to the controller - does it show up in the request headers? if so - you can manually set a request header in rspec using `request.headers['header-name'] = value` (which you do before the `get`)